# Facebook iOS SDK pulling friends data issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to implement Facebook iOS SDK 3.1.1 into my app and I'm having issues.

When I try to run

```
NSString *query =
@"SELECT uid, name, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid IN "
@"(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() LIMIT 25)";
// Set up the query parameter
NSDictionary *queryParam =
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:query, @"q", nil];
// Make the API request that uses FQL
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/fql"
                             parameters:queryParam
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error) {
                          if (error) {
                              NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                          } else {
                              NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
                          }
                      }];
```

My app crashes on `NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);` If someone could help me out that would be much appreciated. I'm trying to return the user's friends list with each friend's user data. Below is the Debug Navigation view.

Thanks,

Wes

[image: Debug Navigation]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rebuild my project from scratch by adding each controller and library back into an empty project. It appears now everything is working correctly. Same code same spot.

Answer (score 2):

The result you can expect here is a dictionary containing all the friend data you need. You can make sense of it like this:

```
NSDictionary *resultDict = (NSDictionary *)result;
NSArray *friendsArr = [resultDict objectForKey:@"data"];
NSMutableArray *resultArr = [NSMutableArray array];
for (FBGraphObject *friendObj in friendsArr) {
    NSString *name = [friendObj objectForKey:@"name"];
    NSString *imageUrl = [friendObj objectForKey:@"pic_square"];
    long long uid = [[friendObj objectForKey:@"uid"] longLongValue];
}
```

Comment: When I tried to add that to replace "NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);"  I got a breakpoint at "for (FBGraphObject *friendObj in friendsArr) {" Same issue. Is there any setup I need to do in this controller? When I look at the FBSettings LoggingBehavior I'm getting the Response data with name, pic_square, and uid but once I try to log it or use the id result it crashes.

Comment: Are you certain there is no error? Try understanding what type "result" is by logging its class name.

Comment: Also, check why the crash occurs - is this because an unrecognized selector was sent to an instance? You added the call stack but not the actual crash log.

Comment: It's a FBGraphObject

The crash says 
-[FBGraphObjectArray objectAtIndex:] at FBGraphObject.m:415:
0xb46cc:  push   {r7, lr}
0xb46ce:  movw   r1, #29100
0xb46d2:  mov    r7, sp
0xb46d4:  movt   r1, #10
0xb46d8:  add    r1, pc
0xb46da:  ldr    r1, [r1]
0xb46dc:  blx    0x144c7c                  ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0xb46e0:  pop    {r7, pc}

Comment: Try this: Go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql and try the exact same query there, on the same active user you're logged in with. If you can - extract the same access token for this operation.

Comment: The query works correctly and prints out {
  "data": [
    {
      "uid": 234234, 
      "name": "Wes", 
      "pic_square": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-prn1/5730122342421_q.jpg"
    }, 

Even in iOS looking at the LoggingBehavior it pulls the correct data but for some reason always crashes when I try to use the id result in any way

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23862/discussion-between-stavash-and-wes)